# Informix Migrate Schema

Tags: migration, informix

I'm busy trying to migrate an informix database schema (with no data) to an informix database running on a different server.

I have exported the schema from the database using

```
dbschema -t all -d olddb schema.sql
```

Then I am trying to import it into my new database

```
dbimport /tmp/schema.sql -d newdb
```

I am getting the error

```
Cannot open sql script file
```

Looking through informix forums they are saying that this is because it cannot find the sql file but how can that be when I a specifying where it is?

Also if I go into the directory where the sql file is and try

```
dbimport schema.sql -d newdb
```

I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Never mind it seems dbimport won't work in this case because the schema wasn't generated with dbexport.

It worked when I did

```
dbaccess newdb /tmp/schema.sql
```